# Trying to get a string from a website which only has one line

Tags: java, url, web-scraping

Basically I'm trying to get a string from an API,and this API is just a blank page with one line which has all the information needed, and I'm only trying to get a part of that.
This part is an ID which for every person - has the same amount of characters.
The API has for each person this line:
{"id":"anExampleUniqueWhichHas32Charact","name": "Player"}
I kinda changed the code so you'll understand, because I'm using a library dedicated for that, but I'm just trying to get the web scraping right.

So what I tried to do was Web Scrape and get the string.length of that amount.

But it doesn't work.

I know I can also use Regex for patterns, but I don't really know how to use that. Regex would honestly be more helpful in this situation.

```
public void checkAPI() throws IOException {
    String person = userInput.nextLine(); // It's just any name.
    URL url = new URL("https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/" + 
    person);
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    InputStream isr =con.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.length() == 32) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

I currently just expect the line to print, later when it'll work I'll use it for other stuff.
No errors are being thrown.

Comment: The site has one line, why bother checking the line length? Print the line regardless. Debug from there. If you want more help, you need to include the value you receive, the value you want, and some explanation of how the first differs from the second.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], providing a *good* answer is almost impossible as your question is currently written. What is the value of `API`? What is the value of `person`? Are any exceptions being thrown? If so which ones? Why are you checking if `line.length() == 32`? Why not output every line? Better yet, why not use a debugger and inspect the values of variables as the code executes?

Comment: @JonnyHenly I changed it, hopefully you can understand better.
I was checking line.length() == 32 to get that "id"

Comment: The response from Mojang's API is formatted as json, so I would suggest to simply convert the response into a Json object (There are many libraries for that: simple json, gson, org.json). With a json object you can easily get the seperate variables, as the id, name or error messages

Comment: I viewed the source of the [webpage](https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/player) you're reading from. There is only one line with two key-value pairs, remove the check for line length and output the line.

Comment: Java 11 (eleven) introduced the [HttpClient](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html_) class. But if you must use `URLConnection` class, I suggest reading [Dodge the traps hiding in the URLConnection class](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2075162/dodge-the-traps-hiding-in-the-urlconnection-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

The API uses Json. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation

You can use a standard json parser like jackson https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson_(API) to parse and query the result.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(new URL("https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/KrisJelbring"));
System.out.println("Name: "+node.get("name"));
System.out.println("Id: "+node.get("id"));
```

but if you don't like to use jackson you can do it by hand: but that's nonsense and not very stable:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
     int startOfId = line.indexOf("\"id\"") + 4;
     int startOfValue = line.indexOf("\"", startOfId) + 1;
     int endOfValue = line.indexOf("\"", startOfValue);
     System.out.println("id: " + line.substring(startOfValue, endOfValue));
}
```

Comment: How can I use jackson? I've searched up online on how to use it, but I can't import it, I'm pretty sure what I'm using doesn't use Maven, so dependencies won't work, is there any other way to use it?